# Wildcard prefix in route group interfering with route slugs - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route group that contains a wildcard prefix. The prefix is for countries for example website.com/Singapore/home or website.com/America/home.

Some of the routes in this route group have a slug in them.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{country}'], function () { 


Route::get('home', 'HomeController@all');
Route::get('login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::get('user/{slug}', 'UsersController@show'); });
```

The first two routes work correctly. However, the third route which contains a slug corresponding to a user's title is the source of error. The controller that handles this route looks like this.

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $user = User::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
    return view('user.show', compact('user'));
}
```

The slug is confusing laravel and I get this error.

"Trying to get property of non-object", and points to the 'show' function above, specifically the 'user' variable.

I think that laravel is trying to find the slug of the wildcard prefix (which does not exist) instead of the slug of the user. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try to output the contents of `$slug` to be sure? I would expect the first parameter in `show` to be from `{country}` and the second one (which you don't have) to be from `{slug}`. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: I dumped the slug, it is the slug of the country rather than the slug of the user which is desired.

Comment: Add a second parameter to the method `show`. This one should give you the slug.